# Can I call a non static method from a static method?

Tags: java, static

I have shown the full class here in case there is something i need to specifically change. I am wanting to call the "power" method in the main method as you can see in the code but it will not work because one of the methods are static and the other one is not. Doe anyone know of a way around this problem? All help appreciated!

```
public class Power
{
    public  int square(int x){
        return x*x;
    }

    public int cube(int x){
        return power(x, 3);
    }

    public int hypercube(int x){
        return power(x, 4);
    }

    public  int power(int x, int n)
    {
        if (n==1)
           System.out.println(n);

        if (n==2)
            square(x);

        if (n==3)
            cube(x);

        if (n==4)
            hypercube(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 6;

        Power p = new Power();

        System.out.println( "The square of " + x + " is: " + power( x, 2 ) );

        System.out.println( "The cube of " + x + " is: " + power( x, 3 ) );

        System.out.println( "The hypercube of " + x +" is: " + power(x, 4));
    }
}
```

edit:
I have made the changes but i am getting a Stackoverflow error on lines 15, 26 and 34. here is the changed code.

```
public class Power{

    public static int square(int x){
        return x*x;
    }


    public static  int cube(int x){
        return power(x, 3);
    }

    public static int hypercube(int x){
        return power(x, 4);
    }




    public static int power(int x, int n){
        if (n==1){
            System.out.println(n);
        }

        if (n==2){
            square(x);
        }
        if (n==3){
            cube(x);
        }
        if (n==4){
            hypercube(x);
        }
        return x;


    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 6;

        System.out.println( "The square of " + x +
                " is: " + power( x, 2 ) );

        System.out.println( "The cube of " + x +
                " is: " + power( x, 3 ) );

        System.out.println( "The hypercube of " + x +
                " is: " + power( x, 4 ) );
    }    
}
```

line 15 is:

```
return power(x, 3);
```

line 26 is:

```
if (n==1){
```

line 34 is:

```
cube(x);
```

Comment: You have the instance in `P`.

Comment: You can either change your methods to static and call them from main or access them via your instance of p.  I recommend instead using `java.lang.Math` ;-) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html  For the sake of what your trying to do, you likley want static methods...

Comment: All of those functions should be `static`, as none of them rely on any instance variables. They are "stand-alone".

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone, i have now made all of the methods static and included the return statement in the power method. The only problem now is that I am getting a stack overflow error, any ideas why that may be?

Comment: @user3006216 what line is causing the stack overflow?

Comment: @user3006216: see my post for the stackoverflow.

Comment: @FunctionR i am getting the error on lines 26, 15 and 34 at "Power.power" and "Power.cube"

Comment: @user3006216 You mean you get the error when you call your `power()` method right? Also, edit your code above to show new changes.

Comment: @FunctionR I have posted the code above in an edit and the specific problem lines. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call a non-static method from a static one. The main reason is that a non-static method does not exist unless an object has been created for it already. The static method can be called without having an instance of that class.

[Quick Explanation of Static Methods in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634224/what-is-the-meaning-of-static-in-a-method-header)

[In-depth Explanation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/21function/)

---

### Fixing all the Problems in Your code

<strike>Your `power()` method does not return anything</strike>.

You have some weird-recursive-problem in your method calls. You need to check how you are delegating the `cube()` and `hypercube()` logic.

---

```
public class Power
{
   public static int square(int x)
   {
      return x*x;
   }

   public static int cube(int x)
   {
      return x*x*x;
   }

   public static int hypercube(int x)
   {
      return x*x*x*x;
   }

   public static int power(int x, int n)
   {
      if (n==2)
        return square(x);

      if(n==3)
        return cube(x);

      if(n==4)
        return hypercube(x);

      return x;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int x = 6;

      System.out.println( "The square of " + x + " is: " + power(x, 2));

      System.out.println( "The cube of " + x + " is: " + power(x, 3));

      System.out.println( "The hypercube of " + x + " is: " + power(x, 4));
   }
}
```

---

### Learning task for you!

This will work, however, you can definitively improve this code further. Think about this: how can you **reuse** the `square()` method to calculate `cube` and `hypercube`.

Comment: I have upvoted your question but... I recommend finding a better explanation of `static` as this is a `Java` question not a `C/C++`

Answer (score 0):

Make all the functions static.

Tip: All functions that do not access non-static fields or functions of the class can be made static.

In this case the functions only use their parameters and can therefore be made static.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements...

In the case you presented it looks more like you need static methods rather than dealing with an Instance of Power.

As one of the other answers states, if your not accessing any instance variables you should set your methods to `static`.

For example:

`public static int power(int x, int n)`

Now from main you can do:

`System.out.println( "The square of "  + x + " is: " + Power.power( x, 2 ) );`

and do away with `Power p = new Power();`

If indeed you are being asked to use a `Power` object as an Instance.

It will be as simple as:

`System.out.println("The square of " + x + " is: " + p.power(x, 2));`

If you are trying to write your own math functions.  STOP and use   `java.lang.Math`  More info can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

See the code below as an example:

```
class Cal {
    int cube(int x) {
        return x * x * x;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //int result=Cal.cube(6);
        //Cal q=new cal();
        //q.cube(6);
        System.out.println(Cal.cube(6));
    }
}
```